# how to implement "Ticker" library of ESP8266 on Arduino?

Tags: timer, arduino, interrupt, esp8266, ticker

I previously wrote some codes for ESP8266 and now I'm trying to use it for Arduino UNO. I'm using internal `Ticker` library of ESP8266 to call a function which implements a programming watch dog. so when the program hangs for any reason, the ticker calls a function on its time and it will do some stuffs and then restarts the program.

the problem is that Arduino hasn't such library and similar libraries on the Github needs to call something like `update` function on the `loop`. so I can't use them because if the program gets hanged, `update` can't be called.

[this link](https://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Timer-Interrupts/) describes how to do it, but I don't want to play with registers and I prefer a good library for this purpose. does anyone know any good library which can help me?

Comment: use the WatchDog library

Comment: @Juraj thanx for answering. I have a question: is there any difference between using WDT for calling a function at specific interval and using Timer for that? which one is better?

Comment: you want to use it for watchdog or not?

Comment: @Juraj Its a programming watch dog. I call a function to check if the dog has feeded. if not, I'll do some logging and then restarting the system

Comment: with WatchDog library you can use the watchdog interrupt to do the logging and then reset. the watchdog interrupt fires only if the dog was not fed

Comment: Check this out: https://circuits4you.com/2018/01/02/esp8266-timer-ticker-example/